# How to get latest version of package in flutter create template

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am modifying my default template file from my flutter installation directory here
`C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\templates\app\pubspec.yaml.tmpl`

```
dependencies:
  #omitted
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

  mobx: latest
  flutter_mobx: latest
```

I am getting this error
`Invalid version constraint: Could not parse version "latest". Unknown text at "latest".`

How do i get the latest version instead of specifying specific version like `^1.x.x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no latest, you have to specify the version number or you can use `any`:

> any
>
> The string any allows any version. This is equivalent to an empty version constraint, but is more explicit. **Although any is allowed, we don’t recommend it.**

https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies

To update your dependencies to the latest version you can do the following:

> Use `pub upgrade` to update to the latest package versions that your pubspec allows. To identify dependencies in your app or package that aren’t on the latest stable versions, use `pub outdated`.

Answer (score -1):

try this after the package that you want the latest

```
 http: ^{latest version}
```